# IIS Rule to Redirect certain paths to another domain

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am looking for help to write a URL rewrite rule for IIS.

I want the rule to ignore the following 
ttp://localhost:8080/**myapp**/somepag.html and serve it from another site running on IIS.

I want to do a URL rewrite on the following 
ttp://localhost:8080/**theirApp**/somepage.html 
and serve the content back to the browser as if it came from localhost

I know the second bit can be done, as we use it to "reverse proxy" a Restful web service. What I dont know if if I can set the "theirApp" condition

```
<rule name="Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^theirApp/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/?$"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.theirApp.com/{R:1}" />
      <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTP_X_UNPROXIED_URL" value="??????????" />
        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST" value="{HTTP_HOST}" />
        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
      </serverVariables>
    </rule>
```

I've also tried :

```
<rule name="all domains to www.domainB.com/my-folder" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^theirApp$" ignoreCase="true" /> 
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.theirApp.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

Where R1 I am thinking is the rest of the URL after the theirApp

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Folks,

The problem wasn't the Rewrite rule I was using so much as I had not properly configured the IIS ARR module on Azure this site [Use Azure as a Reverse Proxy Helped me out.](http://ruslany.net/2014/05/using-azure-web-site-as-a-reverse-proxy/)